# Appium Grid set up

Tags: grid, appium

I am using Appium for mobile automation.

I have started hub and node with below command.

**hub**

```
java -jar jarname -role hub -port 4723
```

**node**

```
node appium -a hubipaddress  -nodconfig node.json -u udid
```

I am able to launch hab and node.But at the time of execution i am getting below error on the hub `"DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,server response code : 500"`

Comment: can you post your node config file.

Answer (score 0):

This must be something wrong with your node.config file, Check that you are using the right host and hubHost servers, check out port numbers etc'. this is probably to a collision with configurations.